# What's the most efficient way to pull data from a table in JS

Tags: javascript

Just wanted to start by saying I'm entirely new to JS. I've barely used it, and am still learning the ropes. Sorry if this is a dumb question!

I'm trying to find a way of pulling data from the second column of a table / 2D array based on the find of the search result from the first column. For example:

```
| Search Column   | Result Column  |
|=================|================|
| SearchThingOne  | ResultThingOne |
| SearchThingTwo  | ResultThingTwo |
| FindThisThing<3 | JSShowThisPlz! |
```

So, if I had a had the Javascript search for `SearchThingOne`, it would provide a result of `ResultThingOne`, or if I had the Javascript search `FindThisThing<3` it would return `JSShowThisPlz!`.

I'm very willing to learn. I'm sure someone has done this kind of thing before, but I couldn't find much on Google that was helpful. Even a pointer in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure, how your data structure look like, can you give an code example, about that?

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reply. The data is stored in a simple table. Here's an example:
`<html>
<head>
<style>
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Username</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>fake@data.com</td>
<td>UsernameHere</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test@test.com</td>
<td>FakeUserame</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>foo@bar.com</td>
<td>helloworld</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>so@email.com</td>
<td>SOuser123</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>hello@world.com</td>
<td>TreesAreGreen</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Repl Example](https://repl.it/repls/WastefulUsedProcessor)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Username</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fake@data.com</td>
    <td>UsernameHere</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test@test.com</td>
    <td>FakeUserame</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo@bar.com</td>
    <td>helloworld</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>so@email.com</td>
    <td>SOuser123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>hello@world.com</td>
    <td>TreesAreGreen</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Create a method that accepts a data set (`dataSet`) to search, as well as the search key (`key`). Use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to match the provided key to one in the data set.

```
const searchDataSetByKey = (dataSet, key) => {
  return dataSet.find((data) => data[0] === key)
}
```

Parse the table data by querying all table rows and reducing ([`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) the resulting Nodelist using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```
let tableDataSet = Array
.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr'))
.reduce((_tableDataSet, tableRow, tableRowIndex) => {
  if(tableRowIndex !== 0) {
    let tableData = tableRow.querySelectorAll('td')
    let key = tableData.item(0).innerText
    let value = tableData.item(1).innerText
    _tableDataSet.push([key, value])
  }
  return _tableDataSet
}, [])
```

Search the data set using the method.

```
let searchResults = searchDataSetByKey(tableDataSet, 'fake@data.com')
console.log(searchResults)
```

Comment: This example updated to reflect further information provided by original poster.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it:

1. Create a function that receives a string as parameter to match the content of a cell
2. Use a JS selector to get all the rows (). Use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and set this query to a variable
3. Make a loop to go through all the TRs (using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) in this variable
4. Check the children (s, in this case) and check if the FIRST  has a content that matches your function parameter
5. Return the second cell, that contains the value

Let me know if you need a example, i can come back later and show you some code.

Comment: Thank you. This sounds like the kind of thing I'd need! I'm not sure how to build it, but I'll try to do it myself and see what I can make of it. A code example would be appreciated if you have the time though, but no pressure. Trying again and again until it works is all part of the fun!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findValue(findThis) {
  // find the table rows
  const { rows } = document.querySelector("table")

  // converting the rows into array
  const arrayRows = [...rows]

  // find the row, and extract the text
  const { 'cells': [,{'innerText': text}] } = arrayRows.find(({cells: [td]}) => {
    return td.innerText === findThis;
  })
  return text;
}
console.log(findValue('test@test.com'))
```

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Username</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fake@data.com</td>
    <td>UsernameHere</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test@test.com</td>
    <td>FakeUserame</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo@bar.com</td>
    <td>helloworld</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>so@email.com</td>
    <td>SOuser123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>hello@world.com</td>
    <td>TreesAreGreen</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```